# How do I make only some sections readonly for a section group in NSIS?

Tags: nsis

I have a section group, and in this group I have 4 sections.
What I want: make only the first two section readonly for the group, and leave the rest optional, in the uninstall part.

My code is the following:

```
Function un.onInit
    !insertmacro SetSectionFlag ${firstUnSec} ${SF_RO}
    !insertmacro SetSectionFlag ${secondUnSec} ${SF_RO}
FunctionEnd


SectionGroup  "What to delete" groupsec
    Section "un.First part" firstUnSec
        Call "un.DropFirst"
    SectionEnd

    Section "un.Second part" secondUnSec
        Call "un.DropSecond"
    SectionEnd

    Section "un.Third part" thirdUnSec
        Call "un.DropThird"
    SectionEnd

    Section "un.Forth part" forthUnSec
        Call "un.DropForth"
    SectionEnd
SectionGroupEnd
```

But it makes only the group readonly, and every section inside the group are optional! Why is that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code that uses the section index must come after the section itself in the .NSI file.

```
SectionGroup  "What to delete" groupsec
    Section "un.First part" firstUnSec
        Call "un.DropFirst"
    SectionEnd
SectionGroupEnd

Function un.onInit
    !insertmacro SetSectionFlag ${firstUnSec} ${SF_RO}
FunctionEnd
```

You don't need any code if it's always read only, you can set the section attribute at compile-time:

```
SectionGroup  "What to delete" groupsec
    Section "un.First part" firstUnSec
        SectionIn RO
        Call "un.DropFirst"
    SectionEnd
SectionGroupEnd
```